Bootstrap modal or canvas gets larger each time called
I am using bootstrap and an implementation of a signature pad from [https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad][1]
The problem is, each time I call the modal to capture a signature the modal (and signature-pad canvas) gets larger each time its called. Here is the css/html and code I have :
#sig-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f8f9fa; /* Light grey background color for the signature area */
        border: 1px solid #ced4da; /* Light grey border for better visibility */
        padding: 10px; /* Padding to ensure the canvas doesn't touch the borders directly */
    }

    #signature-pad {
        /*width: 100%;*/
        width:100%;
        height: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        touch-action: none;
        user-select: none;
    }


div class="modal" id="sigModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">

            <div class="card-header card-header-warning" id="showCustName">
               None
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">

                <div id ="sig-wrapper">

                    <canvas id="signature-pad" class="signature-pad"></canvas>
                </div>

            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id = "cancelButton" type="button"  class="close mr-1" data-dismiss="modal" >Cancel</button>
            <button id = "clearButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1"  >Clear</button>
            <button id = "saveBut" type="button" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Ok</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

In the doc ready event I initialize the elements:
 $(document).ready(function() {

var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
signaturePad = new SignaturePad(canvas);
    function resizeCanvas() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('signature-pad');
        var wrapper = document.getElementById('sig-wrapper');
        const ratio = Math.max(window.devicePixelRatio || 1, 1);

        // Set canvas width and height to wrapper's dimensions
        canvas.width = wrapper.clientWidth * ratio;
        canvas.height = wrapper.clientHeight * ratio;

        // Reset any previous transformations and scale the context
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        context.scale(ratio, ratio);

        // Clear the canvas
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Clear the signature pad to ensure it's empty
        if (signaturePad) {
            signaturePad.clear(); // Ensure this does not error if signaturePad is not yet initialized
        }
    }

    // window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);

    $('#sigModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        resizeCanvas();
    });
     $('#sigModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {

        pauseInterval = pauseStatus


        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        signaturePad.clear();
    });

})
Can anyone please let me know where I am going wrong ?
Many thanks.

Try replacing clientWidth & clientHeight with offsetWidth and offsetHeight, and see if that helps.
